# Upload artifacts to multiple nexus instances without running build twice using maven

Tags: maven, nexus

We have some legacy reasons to upload our software artifacts to two instances of nexus (one internal and the other with the cloud solution we are hosted with)

Currently, we accomplish the same running the build twice with different settings files

```
mvn clean deploy -s=internal_nexus_settings.xml
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true -s=external_nexus_settings.xml
```

Is there a possibility of uploading artifacts to both without running the build twice

Currently, settings file contain

*external_nexus_settings.xml*

```
     <id>external_cloudprovider</id>
     <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
     <properties>
       <nexus.release.url>https://cloudvendor/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</nexus.release.url>
       <nexus.snapshot.url>https://cloudvendor/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</nexus.snapshot.url>
       <nexus.site.url>dav:https://cloudvendor/nexus/content/repositories/sites/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/</nexus.site.url>
       <nexus.username>admin</nexus.username>
       <nexus.password>mycreds</nexus.password>
     </properties>
```

*internal_nexus_settings.xml*

```
    <profile>
      <id>internal_nexus</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <nexus.release.url>https://internal/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</nexus.release.url>
        <nexus.snapshot.url>https://internal/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</nexus.snapshot.url>
        <nexus.site.url>dav:https://internal/nexus/content/repositories/sites/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/</nexus.site.url>
        <nexus.username>admin</nexus.username>
        <nexus.password>mycreds</nexus.password>
      </properties>
```

Tried adding multiple profiles (activating the profile via default and command line params) but maven picks the settings of the latest profile only

`mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true -s=external_nexus_settings.xml -P internal,external`

Comment: The internal Nexus cannot see the Cloud nexus and vice versa?

Comment: The internal nexus is able to access the cloud nexus, not the other way around for the time being.

Comment: Then you could think about just deploying to the cloud Nexus and setting a proxy from the internal Nexus to the cloud Nexus.